# Mondrian.war missed in mondrian-3.7? How to deploy mondrian 3.7

Tags: c#, tomcat, mondrian

I am trying configuring the latest stable release version of the Mondrian 3.7 using below applications:

- JDK 1.8;
- Apache Tomcat 7.0;
- MySQL 5.6;
- MySQL JDBC driver 5.1.21.

But, unable to get `lib/mondrian.war` from `mondrian-3.7.0.0-752.zip`.

File missing as mentioned [in the document of Mondrian website](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/installation.php#3_Deploy_and_run_the_web_app).

Also there is the [task in JIRA](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/MONDRIAN-2167) for this issue in there website.

Please provide if any other document to deploy this new version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The mondrian project does not ship the web application anymore. There are plenty of UIs out there to connect to Mondrian and the one we used to ship (jPivot) was terribly outdated.

Comment: Thanks you so much Luc. I have used Jpivot to deploy mondrian and how can check xmla(XML for Analysis tester)test as like in older version.